# How to change TabBar items Navigation Title

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm facing a problem ! I have been struggling for days ! My problem is that I'm not able to change the title of navigation in my TabBar items.

First I'm pushing to the **UITabBarViewController** from **App delegate** if the user is already signed in.

```
let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
        if currentUser != nil {
            let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let HomeView : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("4")

            let navigationController = application.windows[0].rootViewController as! UINavigationController
            navigationController.pushViewController(HomeView, animated: false)
        } else {

        }
```

Then in the first item ViewController I'm using this to change the TitleView Image for example.

```
let logo = UIImage(named: "logo.png")
let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
self.navigationController!.topViewController!.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

and in the second item ViewController I'm using this to change the title again.

```
self.navigationController!.topViewController!.navigationItem.titleView = nil
 self.navigationController!.topViewController!.navigationItem.title = "Second"
```

But when I go back to the first item I should see the Image I set, instead I see the title of the second item view controller

Comment: In your code sample i see let HomeView : UIViewController.
Is that the UITabBarViewController in your actual code?

Comment: Yes that's right, I have changed it to : `let HomeView : UITabBarController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("4") as! UITabBarController`

Comment: Please see edited post

Answer (score 2):

Replace

`self.navigationController!.topViewController!.title = "Mes contacts"`

with

```
self.navigationController!.topViewController!.navigationItem.title = "Mes contacts"
```

Comment: Please see Edited post